# How to create alphabet and Input Search in React JS

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I want to filter list by alphabet and search input. On click of each alphabet it should sort the list according to the alphabet.

Attached is the image to explain better [image: Aplhabetic Search]

For example : If you click on **"A"** then it will display list starting with **"A"** Like ( Apple, Air plane, Adidas ) etc. And the case should be same when you input in search input box.

Below is the render function in my component which is fetching the list by JSON API

**component.js**

```
{this.props.items.list.map((item) => (
                                <li key={item.id} className="celeb-item">
                                    <div className="celeb-item-info">
                                    <a href="#"><img src={item.image_url} className="img-responsive" /></a>
                                    <strong>{item.name}</strong>
                                    </div>

                                </li>
                            ))}
```

Comment: have you tried to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) 
 `this.props.items.list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
    class App extends Component {
      state = { searchInput: '', alphabet: ''};
      onSearchInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({searchInput: e.target.value})
      }
      onAlphabetClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({alphabet: e.target.value})
      }
      prepareAlphabets = () => {
        let result = [];
        for(let i=65; i<91; i++) {
          result.push(
            <button type="button" key={i} onClick={this.onAlphabetClick} value={String.fromCharCode(i)} >{String.fromCharCode(i)}</button>
          )
        }
        return result;
      }
      elementContainsSearchString = (searchInput, element) => (searchInput ? element.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) : false);
      filterItems = (itemList) => {
        let result = [];
        const { searchInput,alphabet } = this.state;
        if(itemList && (searchInput || alphabet)) {
          result = itemList.filter((element) => (element.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === alphabet.toLowerCase()) || 
          this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, element));
        } else {
          result = itemList || [];
        }
        result = result.map((item)=> (<li>{item.name}</li>))
        return result;
      }
        render() {
            const itemList = [{id: 1, name:'abcd'},{id: 2, name:'gfhj'}, {id: 3, name:'fh'}, {id: 4, name:'zxbv'}, {id: 5, name:'ewyur'}, {id: 6, name:'gsdjhbndf'}, {id: 7, name:'gbhfvd'}, {id: 8, name:'wgtaqe'}, {id: 1, name:'ab'}, {id: 1, name:'bcd'}, {id: 1, name:'cde'}];
            // const itemList = undefined;
          const filteredList = this.filterItems(itemList);
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="search" onChange={this.onSearchInputChange} />
            {this.prepareAlphabets()}
            <ul>
              {filteredList}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. Do you have any sample for this ? with alphabet button and search ?

Comment: Thanks Ekta for detailed code, I have made some changes to get the data accordingly but I am getting the following error `TypeError: element.charAt is not a function` and I am mapping the data like this `for (let key in celebrity) {
            result.push(celebrity[key]);
            result = this.props.items.celebrity.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.id} className="celeb-item">
                        <a href="#"><img src={item.image_url} className="img-responsive" /></a>
                        <strong>{item.name}</strong>
                </li>
            ))
        }`

Comment: The mapping i am doing in the same function you have created, `filterItems` I would appreciate your further help to finish this.

Comment: I am unable to get the data If i am mapping outside `for (let key in celebrity) {
            result.push(celebrity[key]);`

Comment: I guess your method is working for only strings but not on array objects, Just change this and you will get the error on click of buttons. `const itemList = [
            {"id": "9102","name": "Apple",},
            {"id": "9103","name": "Mango",},
           {"id": "9104","name": "Strawberry",},
           {"id": "9105","name": "Orange",},
            
        ];` ** Please let me know if you find any solution for this. **

Comment: This is the full code of mine for you to check

https://jsfiddle.net/huzefa086/unvagj5e/4/

Comment: Hi Ekta, Thanks for the quick help, Sorry if i am asking too many questions. I am new to ReactJS. Your function works well if I am using static data. But if I am pulling the data from API using redux like below, the alphabet filter stops working. Following the is the function for mapping. ` for (let key in celebrity) {
            result.push(celebrity[key]);
            result = this.props.items.celebrity.map((item) => (
                <li className="item">
                    <strong>{item.name}</strong>
                </li>
            ))
            return result;
        }`

Comment: I have updated the fiddle for full source so you can view the change. [ https://jsfiddle.net/huzefa086/unvagj5e/5/ ] Also the search in your original code display blank result if you start typing in the text box. I really appreciate your help further.

Comment: But how to map then without changing this ? I have the data in this prop `this.props.items.celebrity` I am unable to map the data If i dont use this `for (let key in celebrity) {
            result.push(celebrity[key]);
            result = this.props.items.celebrity.map((item) => (
                <li className="item">
                    <strong>{item.name}</strong>
                </li>
            ))
            return result;
        }`

Comment: Yes, If i do not change anything in that function and try to map then i am getting the error because the function is unable to map the data. But data is fetched properly in the render method as I can log it in console. Following is the render method. `render() {
let celebrity = this.props.items.celebrity
console.log (celebrity);
const filteredList = this.filterItems(celebrity);
}`
Error Snapshot [ https://prnt.sc/lt2q17 ]
Console Snapshot [ https://prnt.sc/lt2qbd ] Here you can see there are 50 items in the array with same format needed. 

Would really appreciate any help

Comment: Hii Ekta, The last change works perfect for mapping, Thank you so much ! By any chance did you checked the search input ?, it does not filter the result. Always shows blank. Kindly check the snapshot. [ https://imgur.com/a/VoVLwX5 ]

Comment: Great EKTA, Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi Ekta, If i change this `&&` to `||` for search then alphabet filter stops working

Comment: hmm, I am not sure but I have not made any big changes to your code. Just changed the object mapping. Please check my full source here if you can observe any problem. [ https://jsfiddle.net/huzefa086/unvagj5e/10/ ]

Comment: Hello Ekta, I have modified the code little but and it works now, just removed that operator and put condition. Let me know if you think this is good `if(itemList && (alphabet)) {
            result = itemList.filter((element) => (element.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === alphabet.toLowerCase()));
          } 
        else if(itemList && (searchInput)) {
            result = itemList.filter((element) => ( 
            this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, element)));
          } else {
            result = itemList || [];
        } `

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not checked that condition. Would you please suggest any changes to make it work ? I tried with `||` as shown in your code but that did not worked for me.

Comment: I have modified the code. Check if it works for you.

Comment: I have checked with your code again, and it works for search after click on alphabet but it is not giving the accurate result which it gives initially before click.
1. Click on any alphabet
2. Then type in search box, it will again render the full list
3. And search will filter till 2nd alphabet correctly, and after putting 3rd alphabet it will stop filtering
Try with this JSON
`"celebrity": [{"id": "9102","name": "Ahoo",},{"id": "9076","name": "Aldaa",},{"id": "9075","name": "Alien",},{"id": "9200","name": "Amal",},{"id": "9035","name": "Alaa",},{"id": "355","name": "Amal Al", },]`

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to achieve what you describe is to chain an **Array.filter** just before your **Array.map**.

You can use the `onChange` & `onClick` handles on your search field and alphabet buttons, respectively, to modify a parameter kept in your components `state`. This parameter could then be passed into your filter, looking something like this:

```js
{this.props.items.list
  .filter(item => item.name.startsWith(this.state.searchValue)
  .map(item => (
    <li key={item.id} className="celeb-item">
      <div className="celeb-item-info">
        <a href="#">
          <img src={item.image_url} className="img-responsive" />
        </a>
        <strong>{item.name}</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
  ))
}
```

Comment: also you would probably have to .toLowerCase() on the item name and search value to make sure it can properly filter your items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Do I have to give A - Z button static in the component ? Or it can be dynamically generated ?

Comment: I have creating something for search input, here is the code `constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {          
          searchterm:'',
        };
        this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind (this);
      }`

`searchHandler(event) {
        this.setState ({searchterm:event.target.value})
    }`

`render() {
        const { searchterm } = this.state;`

`<input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler} value={searchterm}/>`

`{this.props.items.celebrity.filter(searchingFor(searchterm)).map((item) => (`

Can you give some sample for button ?

Comment: Yeah quite a nice pattern for creating more re-usable handler functions is to use a double arrow function. So in the constructor you can write something like:

`this.buttonClick = letter => () => this.setState({ searchTerm: letter})`

Then if have an array containing the letters you want to use you can create a map from that pretty nicely, i.e.:

`{alphabet.map(letter => <button onClick={this.buttonClick(letter)}>letter</button>}`